# Delete all foreign key data on delete of primary or vice-a-versa

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, delete-row

I have table structure like this:

`PrimaryTable` -> `p_id` **Here p_id is primary**

`SecondoryTable` -> `s_id` `p_id` **Here p_id is a foreign key**

`ThirdTable` -> `t_id` `s_id` **Here s_id is foreign key**

`FourthTable` -> `f_id` `t_id` **Here t_id is foreign key**

So I am deleting one of my `p_id` from `PrimaryTable` and want that its `SecondoryTable` data should also get delete AND `ThirdTable` data should be deleted with reference to `SecondoryTable` and `FourthTable` data should be deleted with reference to `ThirdTable`

I know i can write `Delete` query from bottom to top, but how to do for so many levels like this??

I found this but not sure on howto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9847308/1182021

Because its four level hierarchy i am confused.

**EDIT1:**

**What if I want to delete `Primary` on Delete of `Child`**

Kindly suggest.

Comment: [Check this out](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: you need to add on delete cascade options to 2nd, 3rd and 4th tables when you declare the foreign keys. Once you make this change to your tables, you should be able to delete the rows from all 4 tables using only one query.

Comment: @Maximus2012 Ok while creating relations, I declared it in this way: `ON DELETE RESTRICT` AND `ON UPDATE RESTRICT`: So are you suggesting, i should do `ON DELETE CASCADE` AND `ON UPDATE CASCADE`? In my Table structure??

Comment: yes. that is correct. Can you try that and see if that works ?

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls292.htm

Comment: Ok I am trying this now, In the meantime can you please suggest if there any cons of doing this??

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this approach. As long as your relations and constraints are correct (which seems to be the case here), there should be no problem. What you are trying to do is exactly the reason for which foreign key on delete cascade option exists.

Comment: @Maximus2012 So it cascades only child or parent also??

Comment: child based on the changes you make to parent.

Comment: @Maximus2012 What if I want to delete parents on delete of child??

Comment: that is not so straightforward as far as I know (but I may be wrong). Look into this and see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169310/delete-parent-record-if-child-is-not-present for implementing something like this, you might need to make changes to your application code and implement this logic at the application level rather than at the database level.

Comment: for deleting parent, on delete of child, one way to do this would be to get the parent id of the row that you are about to delete, and if the delete is successful, then delete the parent row whose id you stored in a variable before you deleted the child row.

Comment: let me know if that does not make sense and I will add an answer for this case since your initial problem seems to be solved now.

Comment: @Maximus2012 If possible you can please provide an answer for this. As both of your guidence were appropriate to my requirement. Thanks and lot. Lets have an answer, so that I can tick as accepted. So other people can directly route to your answer. Thanks Cheers!

Comment: look at my answer. See if that helps. The answer is sort of pseudo-code and if you need to implement that answer then you need to write code for query execution using MySQLi/PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OP's request, this is an answer for the case when the user wants to delete the row from the parent table when a row is deleted from the child table. The case for recursively deleting all the children when a parent is deleted is working using MySQL ON DELETE CASCADE option.

The 4 tables would be table1, table2, table3 & table4.

If the user wants to delete a row in table2 and also the corresponding row in table1 (parent of table2) then in PHP:

```
// t2_delete_row_id is the id of the table 2 row to be deleted
// get the the parent of table2
$sql_get_parent = "select p_id from table2 where s_id = 't2_delete_row_id '";
// execute this query using MySQLi/PDO to get id of the parent row to be deleted
// assuming that id is t1_parent_row_id
// now delete the row from table 2:
// note that because of the foreign key constraints, 
// corresponding rows from table3 and table4 would also be deleted
$sql_delete_child = "delete from table2 where s_id = 't2_delete_row_id'";
if (mysqli_query($sql_delete_child)){
    // delete the parent row
    $sql_delete_parent = "delete from table1 where p_id = 't1_parent_row_id'";
}
```

this logic can be extended so that on deleting table3 row, corresponding parent(table2) and "grand-parent" (table1) rows would be deleted as well. A bit of recursion might be needed for that case. And this will of course delete the child rows in table4 because of the foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to use FOREIGN KEYS (ie using MyISAM tables) I would create a TRIGGER for this. Example for first one below ... you will need to make one for each table that's cascading.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `pDeleteTrigger` BEFORE DELETE ON `PrimaryTable`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `SecondoryTable` WHERE NEW.`p_id` = `SecondoryTable`.`p_id`
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: so there should be triggers for each table then ?

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey  Then `CASCADE` concept is useless according to your knowledge wow hats off to mysql dev team they developed a feature which is not usefull

Comment: @dianuj I can't tell if your being sarcastic, but `CASCADE` is definatly useful if you are able to use `FOREIGN KEYS` its the perfect solution.  But sometimes you can't use this because you are using MyISAM for full text searches etc etc

Comment: I agree with Christopher. This solution will work for MyISAM table. Additionally, as per OP's 2nd request, the trigger functionality can be extended to delete the parent row on deleting a child row. My answer shows how to do this in PHP but this could be used to do that entirely in database.

Answer (score 0):

I have two approachs in my mind  (if your language is Tsql)

**1.-  Store procedure**

The idea is  have a procedure  "spDelete_PrimaryTable", so that you can delete the registers in the four tables by writinf something in tsql like:

```
 exec spDelete_PrimaryTable
       @p_id= 25 /* (25 or watever p_id of primary table you want to delete)*/
```

(yes you can call it from  vb.net or watever you want to.)

the code would be something like:

```
use [your_database]

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDelete_PrimaryTable]
    @p_id nvarchar(MAX)
AS 
 begin  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

delete from FourthTable where t_id in (
    select ThirdTable.t_id 
    from ThirdTable inner join SecondoryTable on ThirdTable.s_id = SecondoryTable.s_id
    where SecondoryTable.p_id = @p_id
)
go

delete from ThirdTable where s_id in (
    select SecondoryTable.s_id 
    where SecondoryTable.p_id = @p_id
)
go

    /*Lol, I forgot to eliminate from the "SecondoryTable" */
    delete from SecondoryTable.s_id 
    where SecondoryTable.p_id = @p_id

go

delete from PrimaryTable where p_id = @p_id
go

 END


GO
```

**2.-  Triggers**

seems like "Christopher Morrissey" have already posted that while i was editing this answer XP