# Django Delete Child record if Parent is not present

Tags: sql, django, orm

How to delete all child records if Parent record is not present.

During migrations I am getting this error.

```
utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixtures: insert or update on table "girvi_transactionauditlogentry" violates foreign key constraint "girv
ionauditloge_credit_id_d8df902_fk_girvi_credit_id"
ey (credit_id)=(5) is not present in table "girvi_credit".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a small script:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    # ...

class B(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(A)
    # ...
```

script:

```
for b in B.objects.all():
    if not b.parent:
        b.delete()
```

and then run your migration again

Comment: Yeah. But I thought why not achieve this by writing a SQL query like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169310/delete-parent-record-if-child-is-not-present  instead of writing `loops and if` ....  thanks

Comment: I would never work directly with SQL once I have django models

Comment: No I was trying to write a query by using Django ORM and same time I was afraid that at the end I'll have to do this :) ... you are right Django ORM rocks ..............